# What would cause this code to produce a file lock error?

Tags: c#, .net, file

The code below writes to a text file in a while loop and sometimes it will produce an error saying that the "The process cannot access the file because its being used by another process" etc..."
The error usually happens on "using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath)) "
Is there a way to check the file is no longer being used or a way to dispose of the text writer properly?

```
 if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                        TextWriter sud = File.AppendText(filePath);
                        sud.WriteLine(GenericLIST[testloop].ToString());
                        sud.Close();
                        sud.Dispose();
                        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath)) 
                        {
                            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                            {
                                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                                {
                                    richTextBox1.AppendText(sr.ReadLine());
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    }

                else
                {

                    TextWriter sud = new StreamWriter(filePath);
                    sud.WriteLine(GenericLIST[testloop].ToString());
                    sud.Close();
                    sud.Dispose();
                    }
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: IMHO, I'd simplify the code to use the various static methods of File (AppendAllText, ReadAllText, WriteAllText) - that's even simpler than remembering to do using's for the TextWriter instances, for instance :)

Comment: using Windows 7 and tested it on a Windows XP Pro machine as well and it produced the same results.
Gonna try James Manning's suggestions sometime tomorrow and see if that works better

Answer (score 5):

I've always used:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
{
}
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx), File.OpenRead is the same as:

```
new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

(the difference being FileShare of Read vs ReadWrite)

Answer (score 1):

Use the excellent ProcMon and have it filter to all access done to the file and you should see which other process(es) are accessing the file.  I've used it for this in the past and it's awesome for this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you release  the file you were appending to read it again.

Between the `sud.Close()` and `using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))` ANY other process running on your computer can take a look and a lock on your file.  The Index service, or anti-viruses is often guilty of this.

Try to disable indexing on the folder, and see if your bug still happens so frequently.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow as well, also do you think the while loop when writing the contents of the file to the richtextbox could be causing this error?

Comment: Since you don't release the lock in the while loop, it shouldn't happen

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Are you using this file anywhere else? Perhaps you have another place in your code where you are missing a Dispose?

I'd also suggest that you use `using` consistently. There are a couple of places where you didn't and an exception thrown there could cause your file to not be disposed correctly.

Comment: yes it works 75% of the time but I need it to work 100% or at least 95% of the time. also could you elaborate some on the use of "using" consistently as I don't think the code I posted could have another one without breaking something